# How to create multiple .md files based on a .csv file and enter the correct rows of the .csv file into each newly created .md file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, markdown

Basically I have a .csv file with similar data structure to the following:

```
Name | Department | Committees | Years

Jack | Finance    | Party      | 7.0
Jen  | Marketing  | Risk       | 15.0
```

I would like to be able to create individual markdown files based on the Name column in the .csv and then write into each Markdown file, the [Department][Committees][Years] info for each person in this format:

- [[Finance]]
- [[Social]]
- [[University]]
- [[7]]

So far I have been able to figure out how to create the individual Markdown files by Name but I cannot figure out how to write the correct data inside the file and format it accordingly.

Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = pd.read_csv("Employee_Directory.csv")
names = data.Name.to_list()

for n in names:
    name = n.split(", ")
   
    file_name = name[0].replace("\n", "") + ".md"

    new_file = open(file_name, "w+")
    new_file.write = ""
    new_file.close()

print("Success")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataFrame from csv file
data = pd.read_csv("Employee_Directory.csv", sep=',', engine='python', encoding="utf- 
8").fillna('')

# Filtering out unwanted characters
data['Committees']=data['Committees'].str.replace("<br>","]] [[")
data['Committees']=data['Committees'].str.replace("-"," ")
data['Associations 1']=data['Associations 1'].str.replace("<br>"," ")
data['Associations 2']=data['Associations 2'].str.replace("<br>"," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace("<br>","]] [[")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace("+","]] [[")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace("-"," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace("/"," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace(":"," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace(")"," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace("("," ")
data['I am a Resource For']=data['I am a Resource For'].str.replace(",","]] [[")
data['Education 1']=data['Education 1'].str.replace("<br>"," ")
data['Education 2']=data['Education 2'].str.replace("<br>"," ")

# Set the names column to a list
names = data.values.tolist()

# Loop through each name, create .md file, set contents to string
for name in names:
    fname = str(name[0])
    file_name = f'{fname}.md'
    dept = str(name[1])
    comm = str(name[2])
    assoc_one = str(name[3])
    assoc_two = str(name[4])
    canbim = str(name[5])
    resource_for = str(name[6])
    #skills = str(name[7])
    edu_one = str(name[8])
    edu_two = str(name[9])
    #degrees = str(name[10])
    years = str(name[11])

    # Write Contents to .md formatted as required
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(f' | Name: {fname} | \n | Department: [[{dept}]] | \n | Committees: 
        [[{comm}]] | \n | Associations 1: [[{assoc_one}]] | \n | Associations 2: 
        [[{assoc_two}]] | \n | CanBIM Level: [[{canbim}]] | \n | I am a resource for: 
        [[{resource_for}]] | \n | Education 1: [[{edu_one}]] | \n | Education 2: 
        [[{edu_two}]] | \n | [[{years} Years with Studio]] |')
        f.close()
    print(f'{file_name} saved.')
```